# Image Similarity with Multi-Label Classification

Tags: pytorch, embedding, cosine-similarity, multilabel-classification, fast-ai

I have trained a multi-label classification model using transfer learning from a ResNet50 model. I use fastai v2. My objective is to do image similarity search. Hence, I have extracted the embeddings from the last connected layer and perform cosine similarity comparison. The model performs pretty well in many cases, being able to search very similar images from the data pool. However in some cases, the model is unable to predict any labels and the embeddings of these images are almost identical, so the cosine similarity is 1.0. The search results thus become very misleading, as none of the images are similar. Are there any ways to solve this issue? I imagine this is quite common but I can't seem to find any discussion about this in online articles/blog posts etc.

A few ways I can think of are:

1. Force the model to always pick at least one output label (class), so the embeddings would not be identical. But I have no idea how to do this. All articles I read about multi-label classification model is that it may not pick any label because labels are not mutually exclusive, unlike single label classification model.
2. Extract embeddings from earlier layers from ResNet50. I feel this might be a viable solution but again I have no idea which layers are good choices.
3. Train another model and extract another set of embeddings. If the current model fails to pick an output label, use the other model. This feels like trial-and-error and doesn't necessarily solve the issue on a fundamental level.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What is your explicit definition of "similarity"? I.e. how do you evaluate model performance?

Comment: In any case depending on your dataset label distribution you may learn a model biased towards negative label predictions (i.e. if 90% of examples do not have label A, it is the safest bet loss-wise to predict negative for label A.) In this way, you could end up with a model that tends to predict negative labels for every label. You can counteract this by weighting examples by label frequency such that the full set of negative and positive examples for each label receive equal weight, which would tend to yield a more expressive label "embedding" I suspect.